# How to connect to rilproxy on Gecko

Tags: firefox-os, b2g

I am working on Firefox OS with Gecko v 1.3.
I am getting error as below when i try to call(MO call).

> D/RIL_QC_B2G(  472): [SUB0] [0000]> DIAL 9900110046 0
>
> E/RIL_QC_B2G(  472): [SUB0] Socket to RIL proxy is closed; ignoring request
>
> D/RIL_QC_B2G(  472): [SUB0] [0001]> GET_CURRENT_CALLS
>
> E/RIL_QC_B2G(  472): [SUB0] Socket to RIL proxy is closed; ignoring request
>
> D/RIL_QC_B2G(  472): [SUB0] [0002]> LAST_CALL_FAIL_CAUSE
>
> E/RIL_QC_B2G(  472): [SUB0] Socket to RIL proxy is closed; ignoring request
>
> D/RIL_QC_B2G(  472): [SUB0] [0003]> SET_DATA_SUBSCRIPTION
>
> E/RIL_QC_B2G(  472): [SUB0] Socket to RIL proxy is closed; ignoring request

Can some one please explain me how to connect to rilproxy.
I have check gecko/ipc/ril/Ril.cpp and gecko/ipc/unixscocket/Unixsocket.cpp but it is fine without any issue

Comment: issue is related to [link](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=842334). This issue is fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue is related to Bug 842334 [link](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=842334).
This issue is fixed now